# Picturebox muestra sólo el fondo, no la imagen

Tags: c#, video, picturebox

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que utiliza una cámara IDS para grabar video y mostrarlo en un `Picturebox` por medio de su handler y tiene un botón que debería parar el video y dejar el último frame en el `Picturebox` para que pueda dibujar sobre él.
El problema surge cuando trato de cargarle el archivo de parámetros (brillo, balance de blancos, etc), después de eso si paro el video y le asigno el último frame al atributo `Image` no se muestra la imagen, sólo se ve el fondo. Si no cargo los parametros eso funciona sin problemas.
En el evento `Paint` que es donde muestra sólo el fondo he intentado guardar la imagen y sí es la correcta, sólo se muestra mal en el `Picturebox`.

El código es el siguiente:

```
private void InitCamera()
    {
        Camera = new Camera();
        uEye.Defines.Status statusRet = 0;

        // Open Camera
        statusRet = Camera.Init();

        if (statusRet != uEye.Defines.Status.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Camera initializing failed");
            Environment.Exit(-2);
        }

        // Allocate Memory
        statusRet = Camera.Memory.Allocate();

        if (statusRet != uEye.Defines.Status.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Allocate Memory failed");
            Environment.Exit(-2);
        }

        // Connect Event
        Camera.EventFrame += onFrameEvent;
    }

private void onFrameEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Camera camera = (Camera)sender;
            int s32MemID;
            camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);
            camera.Display.Render(s32MemID, displayHandle, uEye.Defines.DisplayRenderMode.FitToWindow); // displayHandle es el handler del picturebox
    }

private void fnStartVideo()
    {
        // Start Live Video
        uEye.Defines.Status statusRet = Camera.Acquisition.Capture();

        if (statusRet != uEye.Defines.Status.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Start Live Video failed");
        }
        else
        {
            bLive = true;
        }
    }

private void btnLoadParameters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bLive)
        {
            Camera.Acquisition.Stop();
            bLive = false;
        }

        int[] memList;
        Camera.Memory.GetList(out memList);
        Camera.Memory.Free(memList);
        Camera.Parameter.Load(""); // Abre un OpenFileDialog para el archivo de parametros
        Camera.Memory.Allocate();

        if (!bLive)
        {
            Camera.Acquisition.Capture();
            bLive = true;
        }
    }

private void btnFreeze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Camera.Acquisition.Freeze() == uEye.Defines.Status.Success) // Pause el video
        {
            int s32MemId = 0;
            bLive = false;
            Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemId);
            Camera.Memory.ToBitmap(s32MemId, out OriginalImage); // Paso el frame actual OriginalImage
            gbBlobs.Enabled = gbFile.Enabled = gbFilters.Enabled = addToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = deleteToolStripMenuItem.Enabled =
            redrawToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
            pbVideo.Refresh();
        }
    }

private void pbVideo_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!bLive)
            {
                if (pbVideo.Image != null)
                {
                    pbVideo.Image.Dispose();
                }

                pbVideo.Image = (Bitmap)OriginalImage.Clone(); // Aquí es donde muestra sólo el fondo, no la imagen
            }
    }
```

Comment: El problema que veo con esta pregunta es que parece ser un problema mas bien de la librería que utilizas (`Camera`) que,para empezar, no sabemos cual es (a no ser que sea una aplicación UWP en cuyo caso deberías especificar en los tags). Sin esos detalles, probablemente sea complicado que recibas ayuda...

Comment: ¿Aunque saque el frame a un ´Bitmap´ y ese se lo asigne a la imagen del ´Picturebox´ crees que sea la librería?
Porque cuando hago un Picturebox.Image.Save o un Bitmap.Save con esa imagen sí la guarda correctamente.

Comment: No se, en realidad es un poco complejo responderte. El problema lo tienes despues de llamar a `btnLoadParameters_Click`?

Comment: Sí. Si hago lo mismo antes de cargarle los parámetros la imagen se muestra bien.

Comment: Como digo,sin poder probarlo es complicado. Es posible que, por alguna razón, se pierda el enlace del evento `Paint` del `picturebox` con el método `pbVideo_Paint `? Puedes depurar a ver si despues de cargar los parámetros sigue disparándose el evento?

Comment: Sí sigue disparándose. Ya había comprobado eso, a simple vista no parece tener nada raro ninguno de los atributos del ´Picturebox´.

Comment: En ese caso, es posible que sea problema de memoria. Esos `Camera.Memory.Free();` y `Camera.Memory.Allocate();` dan un poco de mala espina. Lamento no poder ayudarte mas, pero necesitaría un [mcve] para poder echarle un vistazo :)

Comment: Tienes razón, el problema parece estar en esos dos métodos.
Si los quito si se ve la imagen en el picturebox, el problema es que se ve distorsionada por no liberar la memoria seguramente.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43539714/579895) a ver si es de ayuda